# Azure DevOps Pipeline Resource.Repository Trigger is not working

Tags: azure-devops

I have two repos named ***Project1* and *Project2*** with two branches ***main & dev*** and my default branch is main.

I have one build pipeline for Project1 named ***project1pipeline***, it will be triggered by the main & dev branches. I  added Project2 as ***resources.repositories.repository*** code in the YAML file of Project1. Whenever the commit happened in both of the repos of the main(default branch), it triggers the *project1pipeline*

When I commit some changes in the dev branch of the Project1 repo, it triggers the project1pipeline but When I commit some changes in the dev branch of the Project2 repo, it doesn't trigger project1pipeline.

***Project1 YAML file for the main branch***

```
trigger:
 branches:
   include:
     - main

pool:
  name: default

resources:
  repositories:
    - repository: proj2
      type: git
      name: DevOps/Project2
      ref : 'refs/heads/main'
      trigger: 
       branches:
         include:
           - main
workspace:
  clean: all
steps:
- checkout: self
  clean: true
- checkout: proj2
  clean: true
- task: CopyFiles@2
  inputs:
    SourceFolder: '$(Build.SourcesDirectory)'
    Contents: '**\*.txt'
    TargetFolder: '$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)'
```

***Project1 YAML file for the dev branch***

```
trigger:
 branches:
   include:
     - dev

pool:
  name: default

resources:
  repositories:
    - repository: proj2
      type: git
      name: DevOps-Test/Project2
      ref : 'refs/heads/dev'
      trigger: 
       branches:
         include:
           - dev
workspace:
  clean: all
steps:
- checkout: self
  clean: true
- checkout: proj2
  clean: true
- task: CopyFiles@2
  inputs:
    SourceFolder: '$(Build.SourcesDirectory)'
    Contents: '**\*.txt'
    TargetFolder: '$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)'
```

Note: Both the repo in the same project

Answer (score 1):

This is an expected behavior in Azure Pipeline with resource trigger.

From my test result, the branch resource trigger works corresponding with the default branch set for Project1. Current default branch is main.

Here is the test process:

Project1 dev:

[image]

Project1 main:

[image]

The pipeline using this .yml file will be triggered by commit from:

-Project1 dev

-Project1 main

-Project2 main

Refer to this official doc:https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/resources?view=azure-devops&tabs=schema

If you change Project1 default branch to dev.

The pipeline using this .yml file will be triggered by commit from:

-Project1 dev

-Project1 main

-Project2 dev